# REST:How to make json more concise

Tags: java, json, rest

json is an useful mediatype when devloping a restful url...but these days a problem puzzle me a lot,I convert entity model class to json string directly and  put them into response...but many entity models have one to many ,many to one relation with other models...such as:

```
class Model{
....
List<model2> model2s;
}
class Model2{
...
List<Model3> model3s;
}
...
```

i convert a Model instance to json string ...the length of this json string should be horrible... how to avoid this...Thanks

Comment: You are possibly mixing too many resources. Shouldn't a REST service only serve you single resources? Your application should get the Model and have references to the other models which again should be retrieved with REST as a single resource i.e. `GET /model/1` then from there `GET /model2/1` etc.

Comment: @Dan It is pretty common to have `GET /model` return all or a subset of resource entities.

Comment: @abraham: That leads to the massive amount of data he wants to avoid though. I'm just saying splitting it up might be an option to break it down into smaller pieces, possibly even avoiding redundant retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

You cant, unless you decide to selectively return your data based on some logic. Imagine returning this as an xml, it will be even more 'horrible' ? Or did i totally miss your question?

On a different note. Why would you worry about complexity of the resultant JSON. It will anyways be parsed automatically (either by JavaScript or client of your web service).

If data size is your issue most you can do is to compress your response.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the JSON is a valid concern, especially if the JSON is being parsed/consumed by javascript running in a browser with a slow(er) javascript engine (older IEs, for example).  Even if the data is compressed over the wire, that only impacts delivery.  The full message must still be parsed in the browser.

A few rules/suggestions:

First, reduce the amount of data -- send only the data that the receiving application needs.  In your case, specifically, filter out any instances of `model2s` and `model3s` that the consuming application does not need to see.

If you can't filter out instances, then reduce the amount of data in each instance -- don't encode every field into JSON.  For example, if `model2s` has four fields: `name`, `date`, `summary` and `author`, and the client application only needs `name` and `date`, then only send `name` and `date`.

Finally, remove redundancy from the data.  If the data is denormalized, and `Model2` has copies of data that rightly belong in `Model` (for example), only send that data with the representation of `Model`.  Likewise, if the relationship between `Model2` and `Model3` is many-to-many, only send a single instance of `model3` data, and implement a reference scheme (like YAML does, for example) for the copies.